# Flot jQuery charts - stacked lines with filled area on reverse Y axis

Tags: flot

I am using FLOT to render my charts. My X axis is dates and my Y axis is reversed (max on bottom, min on top). Everything works fine except for the stacked filled lines (filled area between the lines which appears as if the Y axis was not reversed. Any idea how to reverse this two to look natural with the reversed Y axis?

FYI: my chart represents keyword ranking per domain on the google search engine (suggestions for alternative rendering as welcomed)

(this is how it looks now)
[image]

Comment: Do you really need filled areas? The area between the top lines is not  really visible either way. (I would also give a little space between the top line and the border of the chart.)

Comment: I'm confused, you want it to fill down?  Towards the maximum number?

Comment: How exactly are you inverting the axis?

Comment: Have you ever fixed this? 
To @DNS: See this http://biostall.com/inverting-the-y-axis-on-jquery-flot-graph/

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patching the `jquery.flot.js` file (http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js), lines 2401 to 2411, inverting the canvas filling path will do the trick:

```
// now first check the case where both is outside
if (y1 >= axisy.max && y2 >= axisy.max) {
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x1), axisy.p2c(axisy.max));
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x2), axisy.p2c(axisy.max));
    continue;
}
else if (y1 <= axisy.min && y2 <= axisy.min) {
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x1), axisy.p2c(axisy.min));
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x2), axisy.p2c(axisy.min));
    continue;
}
```

You need to change `axisy.max` with `axisy.min` in the first `if` and viceversa in the second. Here the resulting code:

```
// now first check the case where both is outside
if (y1 >= axisy.max && y2 >= axisy.max) {
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x1), axisy.p2c(axisy.min));
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x2), axisy.p2c(axisy.min));
    continue;
}
else if (y1 <= axisy.min && y2 <= axisy.min) {
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x1), axisy.p2c(axisy.max));
    ctx.lineTo(axisx.p2c(x2), axisy.p2c(axisy.max));
    continue;
}
```